# Play video not in full screen mode

Tags: iphone, video, size, screen, mode

First, excuse my english :)

I've read on apple developer website that video playback provides by the framework supports only full screen mode.

I will need to develop an application where video can be played in reduce screen mode. I've see that Orange TV make something which looks like what i need to do.

http://img218.imageshack.us/img218/1228/tvplayerorange.jpg
[http://img218.imageshack.us/img218/1228/tvplayerorange.jpg http://img218.imageshack.us/img218/1228/tvplayerorange.jpg](http://img218.imageshack.us/img218/1228/tvplayerorange.jpg)

The application is available on app store but you need to have a subscription to test this application. Whatever, to resume it, we can see video (tv stream video) in a reduce mode and if we click on the screen it switch to a full screen mode.

So my question, what i want to do is possible (Orange TV made it) but i wonder the difficulty to make it. It seems that I have to make a video player. If it take a bunch of time, I tkink I will use Media Player Framework of iPhone even isn't the optimal solution for me.

Feel free to ask me more details ;)

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the MPMoviePlayerController class dump [here](http://ericasadun.com/iPhoneDocs220/interface_m_p_movie_player_controller.html), you can see these public members:

```
-(BOOL) isFullscreen;  
-(void) setFullscreen:(BOOL)fp8;
```

So there is a tiny chance to show a movie in windowed mode. However, these members are not officialy available and may have unexpected behaviour. This is just a hint, I haven't done it myself. Beware that using undocumented APIs may make Apple reject your application from the AppStore.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use the built in media framework to display windowed video. You would have to port another codec and streaming library to iPhone to achieve this.